# Spring + DataSourceTransactionManager + TopLink + Tomcat + Share UnitOfWork across DAO files

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat7, toplink-essentials

In Spring, is there a way I can access the properties of the unitofwork across the DAO's?

Let's assume I have a service layer:

```
public Class A {      
    public doSave (){  
        impl.setUnitOfWork(details);  
        daoA.saveA(dto.getEntityADetails())  
        daoB.saveB(dto.getEntityBDetails());  
    }
}  

public class Impl extends TopLinkDaoSupport {  

    public void setUnitOfWork (TxnDetailsDTO details) {  
        getSection().getTopLinkTemplate().execute (new UnitOfWorkCallback() {  
            protected object doInUnitOfWork (UnitofWork uow) {  
                uow.setProperty ('prop1', details);  
                return null;  
            }  
         });  
     }  
}  

public Class DAOA {  

    public saveA (DTO dto) {  
        getSection().getTopLinkTemplate().execute (new UnitOfWorkCallback() {  
            protected object doInUnitOfWork (UnitofWork uow) {  
                if (uow.getProperty('prop1'))  
                    uow.registerObject(dto);  
                return null;  
            }  
        });  
    }  
}  


public Class DAOB {  

    public saveB (DTO dto) {  
        getSection().getTopLinkTemplate().execute (new UnitOfWorkCallback() {  
            protected object doInUnitOfWork (UnitofWork uow) {  
                if (uow.getProperty('prop1'))  
                    uow.registerObject(dto);  
                return null;  
            }  
        });  
    }  
}
```

Server is Tomcat.

I have a similar implementation done with WebSphere & that works, but with Tomcat I am not able to access it.

Comment: Thanks Dave for the help

Comment: This question isn't related to http://projects.spring.io/spring-integration/. Please, be careful with choosing tags. I can't help you here, sorry. But the question is like a spam in my filter.

Comment: that was a mistake from my side & I removed that tag. Thanks for notifying me.